An error occurs when running the spfx web part. Error - [webpack]
When I create a web part using the command: yo @microsoft/sharepoint, I don't get the local part option.
The following message appears in the browser:

The terminal has the following errors:
[13:55:54] Error - [webpack] Error processing webpack stats: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toJson')
[13:55:54] Error - [webpack] Webpack error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'asyncChunks')

My package.json:
{
  "name": "roundabout-test-task",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0 || >=18.17.1 <19.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.106.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-component-base": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.7": "0.1.0",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.18.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.18.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.18.2"
  }
}

More information about environment:

